# How to remove only one hyphen (first occurance) from the string (file name) in CPP?

Tags: c++, string

How to remove only one hyphen (first occurrence) from the string (file name) in CPP? Suppose I have file name DS-NMDX-2C219-FK. Suppose I want to remove only first hyphen? Between DS-NMDX?

Comment: Hi Gaurav, can you please let us know what you've tried so far? Have you looked at the functions that are available for `std::string`? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Comment: Find it with `find()` and remove with `erase()`, no?

Comment: Unclear bit. what exactly you are expecting. seems to be a removal of a specific character in string that can be achieved very easily.

Comment: @santoshdhanawade His question was very straightforward to me, he is just new. What part was unclear? I can help you understand what he means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David's answer is basically right, but we also need add protection to keep code works in all possible input since '-' might not be found in the input string.

Here is the example code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string input = "DS-NMDX-2C219-FK";
    // .find return the position of first occurence of '-'
    auto pos = input.find('-');
    // '-' might not exist in input, so need protection here
    if (pos != std::string::npos) {
        input.erase(pos, 1);
    }
    std::cout << input << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = 'DS-NMDX-2C219-FK';
cout<< s.erase(s.find('-'),1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find it first, using *find* (Must #include < string >) :

```
int find = str.find("-");
```

This stores the location of the first occurrence of "-" in the int "find".

Then, you can do something like :

```
str.erase(find,1);
```

This starts erasing at position *find* and erases one position.

Working code :

```
int main() {

 string str = "DS-NMDX-2C219-FK"; 

 int finder = str.find("-");  // find the position of -

 str.erase(finder,1);  // start at position of -, erase one position

 cout << str << endl;


return 0;

}
```

Comment: Couple of notes, (1) [std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Allocator>::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) returns `size_type`, e.g. `size_t`, instead of `int`. (2) Would it not be simpler to `str.erase (str.find("-"),1);`?

Comment: You again! :) I decided to keep it simple for him. When I first started coding there were all sorts of ways people wanted me to code. By putting it into separate lines of code, I think it will help him more by keeping it simple. If he's being lazy and wants free code, he has it. But it he wants to learn I think its better to keep it very straightforward. Atleast, just my opinion.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - off topic a bit but with your knowledge of NWS stuff, I have to ask : are you familiar with python? I have a GOES-16 script I have needed help on for months. It might interest you.

Comment: Chuckling.. to me, python is a snake. I can fumble through it with the tutorial open in one window and a script in the other, but only at that level. One of these days I'm going to have to make friends with it, but I came from a fortran and C environment many, many, many years ago and have always stayed with the compiled languages.